# Adding markers on the axis of a waveform graph to select a range of data in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I'm using LabVIEW as part of a LiF rig.
Currently I've got a setup where I enter a range of data points to integrate over (start and end), which is then plotted for a given frequency. What I'd like to do is have all data points plotted, and allow for the range to be selected visually by adjusting two markers on the x-axis of the graph. Has anyone got any advice on how to achieve the second part of this?

Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along this lines using cursors:

1. RMB on XYGraph ->Visible Items->Cursors
2. RMB on cursors -> Add New
3. repeat #2
4. RMB on Cursor1 -> Properties -> Cursor Style -> select vertical line
5. RMB on Cursor0 -> Properties -> Cursor Style -> select vertical line

positions of cursors can be read via property nodes:

1. RMB on xygraph -> Create -> Property node -> Cursor -> Cursor Postions
2. Add Cursor index to the property node: RMB on the property
3. node -> Add element LMB on the topmost property -> Cursor-> Cursor
4. Index RMB on cursor index -> change to write.

You will get something like that on the FP:
[image: XY graph]

and something like that on the BD:
[image: BD]

In order to read cursor X coordinates to perform the integration do like that:
[image: Code snipplet]

PS.
You can drag-and-drop the snipplet image from explorer window to your BD for code to appear (LV2014)